# Master Interface for All Class

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I want to create an Interface that has default method (Save, Update, Delete, Select, SelectByID) for all classes that will inherit this Interface. How can I make a method in an Interface that can accept any class name with object?

```
interface IMasterActions
{
    int Save(Class_Name obj);

    int Update(Class_Name obj);
}
```

```
public class Student
{
    public int RollNo{get;set;}
    public String Name{get;set;}
}
```

```
public class Book
{
    public String Author{get; set;}
    public decimal Price{get; set;}
}
```

```
public class StudentManager:ImasterActions
{
     public int Save(Student std)
     {
         ........
     }
}
```

```
public class BookManager:IMasterActions
{
    public int Save(Book book)
    {
        .............
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the method take no parameter at all? Or even an `IMasterAction`? Why would it take a `Class_Name`? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: What is the purpose of having a common interface for IMasterActions?  Do you need a collection of IMasterActions, or do you want to build a method that accepts an arbitrary IMasterAction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use generics to allow for the dynamic nature of the interface implementations.  Your interface and implementations would be defined as follows:

```
public interface IMasterActions<T> where T : class
{
    int Save(T obj);

    int Update(T obj);
}

public class StudentManager:IMasterActions<Student>
{
    public int Save(Student std)
    {
       ... .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics to achieve this.

```
interface IMasterActions<T>
{
 int Save(T obj);

 int Update(T obj);
}

public class StudentManager:ImasterActions<Student>
{
  public int Save(Student std)
  {
   ........
  }
}
```

More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwtft8ak.aspx